# In deep learning, can I change the weight of loss dynamically?

Tags: deep-learning

Call for experts in deep learning.

Hey, I am recently working on training images using tensorflow in python for tone mapping.  To get the better result, I focused on using perceptual loss introduced from [this paper](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jcjohns/papers/eccv16/JohnsonECCV16.pdf) by Justin Johnson.

In my implementation, I made the use of all 3 parts of loss: a feature loss that extracted from vgg16; a L2 pixel-level loss from the transferred image and the ground true image; and the total variation loss.  I summed them up as the loss for back propagation.

From the function
yˆ=argminλcloss_content(y,yc)+λsloss_style(y,ys)+λTVloss_TV(y)

in the paper, we can see that there are 3 weights of the losses, the λ's, to balance them.  The value of three λs are probably fixed throughout the training.

My question is that does it make sense if I dynamically change the λ's in every epoch(or several epochs) to adjust the importance of these losses?
For instance, the perceptual loss converges drastically in the first several epochs yet the pixel-level l2 loss converges fairly slow. So maybe the weight λs should be higher for the content loss, let's say 0.9, but lower for others.  As the time passes, the pixel-level loss will be increasingly important to smooth up the image and to minimize the artifacts.  So it might be better to adjust it higher a bit.  Just like changing the learning rate according to the different epochs.

The postdoc supervises me straightly opposes my idea.  He thought it is dynamically changing the training model and could cause the inconsistency of the training.

So, pro and cons, I need some ideas...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer this without knowing more about the data you're using, but in short, dynamic loss should not really have that much effect and may have opposite effect altogether.
If you are using Keras, you could simply run a hyperparameter tuner similar to the following in order to see if there is any effect (change the loss accordingly):
https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameter-optimization-with-keras-b82e6364ca53

I've only done this on smaller models (way too time consuming) but in essence, it's best to keep it constant and also avoid angering off your supervisor too :D

If you are running a different ML or DL library, there are optimizer for each, just Google them. It may be best to run these on a cluster and overnight, but they usually give you a good enough optimized version of your model.

Hope that helps and good luck!